# Apex Class that runs queries and updates a custom object

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I created an apex class that acts queries fields and updates a custom object but it is timing out when I try to execute it in the anonymous window. It is still in the sandbox but I don't want to deploy it to production as yet. Can someone take a look and tell me why?

```java
global class ScheduleAccountPlan implements Schedulable{
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc){
        
        List<Account_Plan__c> acctPlanList = new List<Account_PLan__c>();
        List<Account_Plan__c> updateATTEngagements = new List<Account_PLan__c>();
        List<Account_Plan__c> updateATTCaseClinic = new List<Account_PLan__c>();
        List<Account_Plan__c> updateATTLegal = new List<Account_PLan__c>();
        List<Account_Plan__c> updateATTChallengeStudy = new List<Account_PLan__c>();
        List<Account_Plan__c> updateATTLitSearch = new List<Account_PLan__c>();
        List<Account_Plan__c> updateATTDepoPrep = new List<Account_PLan__c>();
        List<Account_Plan__c> updateATTQuickQuestions = new List<Account_PLan__c>();
        List<Account_Plan__c> updateATTClosedNoEng = new List<Account_PLan__c>();
        
        Map<Id, Id> acctPlanIdMap = new Map<Id, Id>(); 
        Map<Id, Integer> myCt = new Map<Id, Integer>();
        Map<Id, Integer> clinicCt = new Map<Id, Integer>();
        Map<Id, Integer> legalCt = new Map<Id, Integer>();
        Map<Id, Integer> challStudyCt = new Map<Id, Integer>();
        Map<Id, Integer> litSearchCt = new Map<Id, Integer>();
        Map<Id, Integer> DepoPrepCt = new Map<Id, Integer>();
        Map<Id, Integer> quickQuestCt = new Map<Id, Integer>();
        Map<Id, Integer> closedNoEngCt = new Map<Id, Integer>();
             
        // query all account plans to get account ids and interate over Account Plans and add Ids and account ids to map
        acctPlanList = [SELECT ID, Account__c FROM Account_Plan__c];     
            for(Account_Plan__c acp : acctPlanList){
                acctPlanIdMap.put(acp.Id, acp.Account__c);
            
        }       
        //Query opps to get the total number of opps by account id where accountId is in account plan map
        AggregateResult[] oppcount = [SELECT COUNT(Id),AccountId FROM Opportunity                                    
                                      WHERE AccountId IN :acctPlanIdMap.values()
                                      AND Type = 'Research'
                                      GROUP BY AccountId];
        
        // interate over aggregateResult and add accountID and opp count to map                                   
        for (AggregateResult Account : oppcount) {          
            Id accountId = (Id)Account.get('AccountId');
            Integer numberOfOpps = (Integer)Account.get('expr0');
            myCt.put(accountId, numberOfOpps);
           
        }
        
        //interate over account plan and assign total account to account plan record 
        for(Account_PLan__c apl : acctPlanList){
            if(myCt.keySet() != null){
                apl.All_Time_Total_Engagements__c = myCt.get(apl.Account__c);
                updateATTEngagements.add(apl);
            }
        }
        
        
        //Query opps to get the total number of Case Clinic opps by account id where accountId is in account plan map
        AggregateResult[] oppClinicCount = [SELECT COUNT(Id), AccountId FROM Opportunity                                            
                                            WHERE AccountId IN :acctPlanIdMap.values()
                                            AND Record_Type_Name__c = 'Case Clinic'
                                            AND Type = 'Research'
                                            GROUP BY AccountId];
        
        // interate over aggregateResult and add accountID and opp count to map                                   
        for (AggregateResult clinicCount : oppCliniccount) {            
            Id accountId0 = (Id)clinicCount.get('AccountId');
            Integer numberOfOpps0 = (Integer)clinicCount.get('expr0');
            clinicCt.put(accountId0, numberOfOpps0);
        }
        
        //interate over account plan and assign total account to account plan record 
        for(Account_PLan__c apl0 : acctPlanList){
            if(clinicCt.keySet() != null){
                apl0.All_Time_Total_Case_Clinics__c = clinicCt.get(apl0.Account__c);
                updateATTCaseClinic.add(apl0);
            }
        } 
        
        AggregateResult[] oppLegalCount = [SELECT COUNT(Id), AccountId FROM Opportunity                                            
                                            WHERE AccountId IN :acctPlanIdMap.values()
                                            AND Record_Type_Name__c = 'Legal'
                                            AND Type = 'Research'
                                            GROUP BY AccountId];
        
        // interate over aggregateResult and add accountID and opp count to map                                   
        for (AggregateResult legalCount : oppLegalcount) {          
            Id accountId1 = (Id)legalCount.get('AccountId');
            Integer numberOfOpps1 = (Integer)legalCount.get('expr0');
            legalCt.put(accountId1, numberOfOpps1);
            }
        
        //interate over account plan and assign total account to account plan record 
        for(Account_PLan__c apl1 : acctPlanList){
            if(legalCt.keySet() != null){
                apl1.All_Time_Total_Expert_Searches__c = legalCt.get(apl1.Account__c);
                updateATTLegal.add(apl1);
            }
        } 
        ///////////////////////////////////////
        AggregateResult[] oppChallengeStudyCount = [SELECT COUNT(Id), AccountId FROM Opportunity                                            
                                            WHERE AccountId IN :acctPlanIdMap.values()
                                            AND Record_Type_Name__c = 'Challenge Study'
                                            AND Type = 'Research'
                                            GROUP BY AccountId];
        
        // interate over aggregateResult and add accountID and opp count to map                                   
        for (AggregateResult challengeStudyCount : oppChallengeStudyCount) {            
            Id accountId2 = (Id)challengeStudyCount.get('AccountId');
            Integer numberOfOpps2 = (Integer)challengeStudyCount.get('expr0');
            challStudyCt.put(accountId2, numberOfOpps2);
            
        }
        
        //interate over account plan and assign total account to account plan record 
        for(Account_PLan__c apl2 : acctPlanList){
            if(challStudyCt.keySet() != null){
                apl2.All_Time_Total_Challenge_Studies__c = challStudyCt.get(apl2.Account__c);
                updateATTChallengeStudy.add(apl2);
            }
        } 
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        AggregateResult[] oppLitSearchCount = [SELECT COUNT(Id), AccountId FROM Opportunity                                            
                                            WHERE AccountId IN :acctPlanIdMap.values()
                                            AND Record_Type_Name__c = 'Other'
                                            AND Category__c = 'Literature Search'
                                            AND Type = 'Research'
                                            GROUP BY AccountId];
        
        // interate over aggregateResult and add accountID and opp count to map                                   
        for (AggregateResult LitSearchCount : oppLitSearchCount) {          
            Id accountId3 = (Id)LitSearchCount.get('AccountId');
            Integer numberOfOpps3 = (Integer)LitSearchCount.get('expr0');
            litSearchCt.put(accountId3, numberOfOpps3);
            
        }
        
        //interate over account plan and assign total account to account plan record 
        for(Account_PLan__c apl3 : acctPlanList){
            if(litSearchCt.keySet() != null){
                apl3.All_Time_Total_Literature_Searches__c = litSearchCt.get(apl3.Account__c);
                updateATTLitSearch.add(apl3);
            }
        } 
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        AggregateResult[] oppDepoPrepCount = [SELECT COUNT(Id), AccountId FROM Opportunity                                            
                                            WHERE AccountId IN :acctPlanIdMap.values()
                                            AND Record_Type_Name__c = 'Other'
                                            AND Category__c = 'Deposition Prep'
                                            AND Type = 'Research'
                                            GROUP BY AccountId];
        
        // interate over aggregateResult and add accountID and opp count to map                                   
        for (AggregateResult DepoPrepCount : oppDepoPrepCount) {            
            Id accountId4 = (Id)DepoPrepCount.get('AccountId');
            Integer numberOfOpps4 = (Integer)DepoPrepCount.get('expr0');
            DepoPrepCt.put(accountId4, numberOfOpps4);
            
        }
        
        //interate over account plan and assign total account to account plan record 
        for(Account_PLan__c apl4 : acctPlanList){
            if(DepoPrepCt.keySet() != null){
                apl4.All_Time_Total_Depo_Preps__c = DepoPrepCt.get(apl4.Account__c);
                updateATTDepoPrep.add(apl4);
            }
        } 
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        AggregateResult[] oppQuickQuestionsCount = [SELECT COUNT(Id), AccountId FROM Opportunity                                            
                                            WHERE AccountId IN :acctPlanIdMap.values()
                                            AND Record_Type_Name__c = 'Other'
                                            AND Category__c = 'Quick Questions'
                                            AND Type = 'Research'
                                            GROUP BY AccountId];
        
        // interate over aggregateResult and add accountID and opp count to map                                   
        for (AggregateResult QuickQuestionsCount : oppQuickQuestionsCount) {            
            Id accountId5 = (Id)QuickQuestionsCount.get('AccountId');
            Integer numberOfOpps5 = (Integer)QuickQuestionsCount.get('expr0');
            quickQuestCt.put(accountId5, numberOfOpps5);
           
        }
        
        //interate over account plan and assign total account to account plan record 
        for(Account_PLan__c apl5 : acctPlanList){
            if(quickQuestCt.keySet() != null){
                apl5.All_Time_Total_Quick_Questions__c = quickQuestCt.get(apl5.Account__c);
                updateATTQuickQuestions.add(apl5);
            }
        }
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        AggregateResult[] oppClosedNoEngCount = [SELECT COUNT(Id), AccountId FROM Opportunity                                            
                                            WHERE AccountId IN :acctPlanIdMap.values()
                                            AND StageName = 'Closed (No Engagement)'
                                            AND Type = 'Research'
                                            GROUP BY AccountId];
        
        // interate over aggregateResult and add accountID and opp count to map                                   
        for (AggregateResult ClosedNoEngCount : oppClosedNoEngCount) {          
            Id accountId6 = (Id)ClosedNoEngCount.get('AccountId');
            Integer numberOfOpps6 = (Integer)ClosedNoEngCount.get('expr0');
            closedNoEngCt.put(accountId6, numberOfOpps6);
            
        }
        
        //interate over account plan and assign total account to account plan record 
        for(Account_PLan__c apl6 : acctPlanList){
            if(closedNoEngCt.keySet() != null){
                apl6.All_Time_Closed_No_Engagements__c= closedNoEngCt.get(apl6.Account__c);
                updateATTClosedNoEng.add(apl6);
            }
        } 
               
        //update account plans
        Update updateATTEngagements;
        Update updateATTCaseClinic;
        Update updateATTLegal;
        Update updateATTChallengeStudy;
        Update updateATTLitSearch;
        Update updateATTDepoPrep;
        Update updateATTClosedNoEng;
        Update updateATTQuickQuestions;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to combine multiple similar aggregate queries into one, add the additional fields into the group by list (`Record_Type_Name__c`, `Category__c`, `Type`).
And you can also combine the update list into 1 list instead.
That aside, I think your aggregation results can be achieved by using Roll-Up Summary field in Account object (with some filter criteria) which would save you from doing this in code.

Comment: lot of database activity here in a single transaction - can you spawn a batchable to delegate work into multiple batchable executes - thus making the transaction size smaller?